# Is there R fucntion for Date format error origin supply

Tags: r

my df1 looks like

```
PID R_date      E_date
123 12-06-2010  12-08-2012
234 13-05-2012  NA
345 14-09-2013  NA
```

and  df2 looks like

```
PID R_date      E_date
123 12-06-2010  12-08-2012
234 13-05-2012  13-05-2012
345 14-09-2013  14-09-2013
```

I have tried to fill the NAs in `E_date` by macthing `PID` of two `df`
using code

```
df1$E_date <- ifelse(is.na(df1$E_date),df2$E_date,df1$E_date)
```

I get output looks like

```
PID R_date      E_date
123 12-06-2010  41133
234 13-05-2012  41042
345 14-09-2013  41531
```

when i tried to supply origin for the date format it shows irrelevant dates like

```
df1$E_date <- as.Date(ifelse(is.na(df1$E_date),df2$E_date,df1$E_date),origin = "1900-01-01")

PID R_date      E_date
123 12-06-2010  06-05-1972
234 13-05-2012  07-06-1988
345 14-09-2013  22-04-1997
```

Comment: Use `dplyr::if_else`

Comment: @Ronak shah it helps correctly